# AJAX return error on request but the php function works

Tags: php, jquery

I run an ajax request trought jQuery that calls a php function that works each time I call it, I don't mean that the written code should work because is right, but it works because I can see the output in the database. However `request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){alert('AJAX Error: '+ textStatus);});` return an error( `parseerror`) , this is my code:

```
$('#createtk').click(function(){
                var tit=$('#title').val();
                var prio=$('#priority').val();
                var wsurl=$('#wsurl').val();
                var dep=$('#dep').val();
                var message=CKEDITOR.instances.message.getData().replace(/\s+/g,' ');
                if(tit.replace(/\s+/g,'')!='' && prio.replace(/\s+/g,'')!='' && dep.replace(/\s+/g,'')!='' && wsurl.replace(/\s+/g,'')!='' && message.replace(/\s+/g,'')!=''){
                    var request= $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '../php/function.php',
                        data: {act:'create_ticket',tit:tit,prio:prio,dep:dep,wsurl:wsurl,contp:$('#contype').val(),ftpus:$('#ftpus').val(),ftppass:$('#ftppass').val(),message:message},
                        dataType : 'json',
                        success : function (data) {
                            alert('1');
                            if(data[0]=='Created'){
                                alert('2');
                                window.location = "<?php echo dirname(curPageURL()); ?>";

                            }
                            else
                                alert(data[0]);
                        }
                    });
                    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){alert('AJAX Error: '+ textStatus);});
                }
                else
                    alert('Form Error - Empty Field');
            });
```

and this is the php function( sorry for the presentation, I put this just for information as it works exe):

```
else if(isset($_POST['act']) && isset($_SESSION['name']) && $_POST['act']=='create_ticket'){ //controllare

$message=(preg_replace('/\s+/','',$_POST['message'])!='')? htmlentities(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$_POST['message']),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'):exit();
$tit=(preg_replace('/\s+/','',$_POST['tit'])!='')? htmlentities(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$_POST['tit']),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'):exit();
$dep=(is_numeric($_POST['dep']))? (int)$_POST['dep']:exit();

$prio=(is_numeric($_POST['prio']))? $_POST['prio']:exit();

$wsurl=(preg_replace('/\s+/','',$_POST['wsurl'])!='')? htmlentities(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$_POST['wsurl']),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'):exit();
$contype=(is_numeric($_POST['contp']))? (int)$_POST['contp']:exit();
$ftppass=(preg_replace('/\s+/','',$_POST['ftppass'])!='')? htmlentities(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$_POST['ftppass']),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'):'';
$ftpus=(preg_replace('/\s+/','',$_POST['ftpus'])!='')? htmlentities(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$_POST['ftpus']),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'):'';

if(preg_replace('/\s+/','',$_POST['message'])!=''){
    $mysqli = new mysqli($Hostname, $Username, $Password, $DatabaseName);
    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
    if($stmt){
        $query = "INSERT INTO ".$SupportTicketsTable."(`department_id`,`user_id`,`title`,`priority`,`website`,`contype`,`ftp_user`,`ftp_password`,`created_time`,`last_reply`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $prepared = $stmt->prepare($query);
        if($prepared){
            $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            if($stmt->bind_param('iisissssss', $dep,$_SESSION['id'],$tit,$prio,$wsurl,$contype,$ftpus,$ftppass,$date,$date)){
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    $tkid=$stmt->insert_id;
                    $ip=retrive_ip();
                    $refid=uniqid(hash('sha256',$tkid.$tit),true);
                    $query = "UPDATE ".$SupportTicketsTable." SET enc_id=? WHERE id=? ";
                    if($prepared = $stmt->prepare($query)){
                        if($stmt->bind_param('si', $refid,$tkid)){
                            if($stmt->execute()){
                                $query = "INSERT INTO ".$SupportMessagesTable."(`user_id`,`message`,`ticket_id`,`ip_address`,`created_time`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";
                                if($prepared = $stmt->prepare($query)){
                                    if($stmt->bind_param('isiss', $_SESSION['id'],$message,$tkid,$ip,$date)){
                                        if($stmt->execute()){
                                            $selopid=retrive_avaible_operator($Hostname, $Username, $Password, $DatabaseName, $SupportUserPerDepaTable, $SupportUserTable, $dep);
                                            if(is_numeric($selopid)){

                                                $query = "UPDATE ".$SupportTicketsTable." a ,".$SupportUserTable." b SET a.operator_id=?,a.ticket_status='1',b.assigned_tickets (b.assigned_tickets+1) WHERE a.id=? AND b.id=? ";
                                                if($prepared = $stmt->prepare($query)){
                                                    if($stmt->bind_param('iii', $selopid,$tkid,$selopid)){
                                                        if($stmt->execute()){
                                                            echo json_encode(array(0=>'Created'));
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                            echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                        echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                                }
                                                else
                                                    echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                            }
                                            echo json_encode(array(0=>$selopid));
                                        }
                                        else
                                            echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                    }
                                    else
                                        echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                                }
                                else
                                    echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                            }
                            else
                                echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                        }
                        else
                            echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                    }
                    else
                        echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
                }
                else
                    echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
            }
            else
                echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
        }
        else
            echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
    }
    else
        echo json_encode(array(0=>mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)));
    $mysqli->close();
}
else
    echo json_encode(array(0=>'Empty Message'));
}
```

The function calls another php function (`retrive_avaible_operator`)  that `retrun` a value and I wonder if this is the problem, Do AJAX/PHP elaborate this information as a final output?
Thanks in advance

Comment: 15 `if's`. My head hurts! ;)

Comment: A parse errors is occurring in your case because jQuery expects a valid JSON string to be returned, but one is not. Check your requests to see exactly what is being returned.

Comment: wow..... what is this?

Comment: @relentless there are 22 `if's` in total. count again.

Comment: It arrives at the final if execute ( i tried to create a file and it works) so the problem should be `echo json_encode(array(0=>'Created'));`, but if I'm not wrong it is an array

Comment: @itachi I'm glad you cleared that up for me

Comment: @relentless there are 15 explicit `if` and 8 `?` so the total is 23, just to proud of my soup

Comment: Nothing to be proud of. If I had to maintain something like that, I'd slam the door, personally.

Comment: geez which 1 i missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My god that is a lot of nested ifs. Have you considered using something called **exceptions** to generate your errors?

I cannot check the return value of your PHP script. However, jQuery expects a json return (as you are setting the dataType to that) and will fail if it gets anything else...including an empty string.

Comment: N.B. to @Dheed, ajax will fail if the coming data is not json even if the requet shows `200 OK` in console.

Comment: It arrives at the final if execute ( i tried to create a file and it works) so the problem should be `echo json_encode(array(0=>'Created'));`, but if I'm not wrong it is an array

Comment: I can post also the other function, put it is even worse than this, however in the end it should throw out `return $selopid;` or `return mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);`

Comment: @Dheed: open your Network Console, find the call, and paste **exactly** the body of the response. If it is not JSON, that's where your problem is!

Comment: It returns:`["Created"][56]`, the first is the echo and the second is the return from the second called function

Comment: `echo json_encode(array(0=>'Created'));` shouldn't generate a json string? Why I see also the `56`(that is return value from the inner function php call)? However the content-type is text/html

Comment: @Dheed: you have another echo/json_encode running after this as `json_encode(array(56))`. Find it. You cannot just concatenate JSON like that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30516/discussion-between-dheed-and-sebastien-renauld)